# jQuery.next() returns empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I'm trying to get the next div after an image:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://localhost:8046/file.htm" class="imgbox">
    <img src="http://www.domain.tld/fm/912/image.png" class="" id="img-1303122" style="max-width:560px;" width="700" border="0" alt="title="/>
</a>
<div id="lic-img-1303122" class="licence-wrapper" style="display:none;">
    <div class="licence-spacer"></div>
    <div class="licence">&copy; copyright<br /></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is the following:

```
console.log($("#img-1303122").nextAll(".licence-wrapper"));
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → JSUmstellung, selector: "#img-1303122.nextAll(.licence-wrapper)" }
```

So, why do I get no result? I already tried .next(), .closest() and .siblings() and none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :-

```
console.log($("#img-1303122").parent().nextAll(".licence-wrapper"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/15/)

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank! Will accept when I'am allowed to!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you are trying to find next element directly to image, but actually div is present next to anchor tag. So get parent anchor tag with `class="imgbox"` and then `.nextAll`

```
console.log($("#img-1303122").closest('.imgbox').nextAll(".licence-wrapper").length);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works too, but Mohit's is a bit easier though

Answer (score 0):

`#img-1303122` doesn't have other divs close by, probably you meant `lic-img-1303122`, next looks only for siblings, from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Comment: So, next just finds elements of the same type?

Comment: From description `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`, so it finds the siblings, but your `<img>` tag is wrapped in a `<a>` and has no siblings.

Comment: @user2225581 next() gets the next element under the same parent. img is the only child of your parent so there is no next. If you want to get the next div you have to use the parent of the image as a selector

Comment: Ah, okay. didn't knew that. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

.nextAll() Gets all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

So you need to try this:

```
$("#img-1303122").parent().nextAll(".licence-wrapper")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can also get all div by this

```
alert($("#img-1303122").parent().parent().find(".licence-wrapper").length);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/shE58/16/)